# Do need to requried install php-fpm and other php library along with HHVM

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, ftp

I have installed HHVM on nginx web server. So I want to know, is it good or required to install php-fpm, php-gd, php-dev, php-mysql, libssh2-1-dev, libssh2-php and other php modules.

Actually on this server I have installed wordpress. Wordpress asked me for ftp for plugin update. I created new ftp user in web server and updated into `wp-config.php` file.

```
define('FTP_PUBKEY', '/home/newftpuser/wp_rsa.pub');
define('FTP_PRIKEY','/home/newftpuser/wp_rsa');
define('FTP_USER','newftpuser');
define('FTP_PASS','password');
define('FTP_HOST','127.0.0.1:22');
```

And then when I tried to open plugins page in wordpress that given me 503 error and when I removed this ftp details from `wp-config.php` then plugin page opens but ask for ftp for plugin updates.

Please guide me solution of this. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/getting-started/getting-started

Comment: @CharlotteDunois thanks for help, But I have already gone through this link. But I did not found any solution there.